# Problem with circumstances and transformations/events

Tags: events

I am trying to find out what is meant by circumstances with respect to transformations.

In the book [Norm and Action by George Henrik von Wright](https://www.giffordlectures.org/lectures/norm-and-action) a transformation is described as a transition from an initial state of affairs to an end state of affairs. For example; Opening the window is viewed as a transformation from an initial state of affairs where there is a closed window, to an end state of affairs where there is an open window.

I have read that the 'circumstance of transformation' as being important when describing the transformations, but the book doesn't say anything about them, so i'm trying to find out what they are. The definition of circumstance i'm struggling to understand is [1.a in the Merriam Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumstance).

For example when the post office fills out forms the initial state of affairs is when there are "blank forms" and the final state of affairs is when there are "filled out forms" and the "instructions and data" are classed as circumstance of transformation.

My problem is that it seems like everything that is in the initial state of affairs could seen as possibly determining or conditoning the transformation. For example the material the form is made out of, the time of day.etc.etc (reduction to absurdity?) are determining factors/circumstances too? Am I misinterpreting the idea of circumstances, because there only seems to be determining factors present.

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 1):

> everything that is in the initial state of affairs could seen as possibly determining or conditoning the transformation

This is demonstrably false. The form will likely be filled out the same way regardless of if the day's weather is sunny or cloudy. If I drop a ball, it will hit the ground regardless of if I'm touching my nose or not. Only certain aspects of the circumstances are causally relevant to the transformation. Sometimes causal relations are non-deterministic and/or outside the reach of current human knowledge, but at a general level they are usually easy to discern.

Comment: Thank you for the reply it is helpful! There seems to be a large number of causally relevant data; for example the kind of grass the ball falls onto.etc. Is there any particular formal method for abstracting away those casual factors that aren't needed for the purpose at hand?

Comment: @RichardBamford In short I would say the answer to that question is the scientific method.... Regarding the case of a ball falling on grass, ask a physicist how they would model this.